# Dell Latitude D430 reboots after "Try Ubuntu without installing"

Tags: boot, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on an old Dell Latitude D430. Both install and live reboot the machine. I've tried all the F6 Other Options to no avail.

I can boot with Hiren's Boot CD and run some of the graphical OS options including Mini-XP and a Seagate Acronis application.

I can boot the Hiren's Linux based rescue environment (Parted Magic 2012-10-10) if I use:

```
    nolapic nopcmcia noscsi nogpm consoleboot nosmart
```

that gets me to the console and if I use

```
    startx
```

the GUI starts OK.

Anyone got any ideas how to beat this?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using the amd64 version but i386 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the netinstall iso (mini.iso) to install xubuntu or lubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD